Failed to write to erl_child_setup: 32. Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
may be similar to Erlang Crash Dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done but the solution didn't work for me.
I am trying to run this "Hello World" Erlang program but keep getting the error Failed to write to erl_child_setup: 32. Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done.
My employer requires that I run it from a docker image (which is at ion606/erlang:24) and I compile/run it with the following:
/usr/local/erlang/26.0/bin/erlc hello.erl
/usr/local/erlang/26.0/bin/erl -noshell -s hello hello_world -s init stop

It compiles but never runs. If it's at all helpful, I opened a PR to try to get help with it here
The full crash dump can be found here
I'm not very good at this kind of thing so please let me know if I should add/remove stuffs, thank you so much for any help ^~^

Did you compile the code on version 26 and then run it on older Erlang version (version on Docker image is 24)..?

sorry my bad yes I named the image the wrong thing. It should be ion606/erlang:26. Weird thing is if I compile it using docker run -it then it works fine, just not on the platform my employer wants
